# How can I produce this tree diagram in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree, qtree

I want to create the tree diagram shown below in TeX code (with the *Level 1... level 3* by the side of the tree diagram). Also, I would like to know how to just put bullet points under a box. For example, *Level 3* instead of *Max Size*, *Casting Complexity*, etc... I want it listed as bullet points from *Product Development capability*.

Any help would be greatly appeciated.

[image]

Comment: Also I would like to know how to just put bullet pints under a box.
For example, Level 3: Instead of 'Max Size', 'Casting Complexity', etc, I want it listed as bullet points from 'Product Development capability'

Comment: Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I have no idea how to attempt it, hence any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you produce your figure with software like powerpoint, save it as .pdf and include it as a figure (adding a figure caption if needed)?

Comment: @Joshua On way to attempt it would be to go to the TikZ gallery (www.texample.net/tikz/examples/‎), find the closest example, and modify the code until it is what you want. The drawing package "tikz" has comparable readable command names, which helps you in doing that in a trial-and-error fashion.

Comment: @Joshua Take a look at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/work-breakdown-structure/ for an example that gets you started.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. So far I have this;

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=72pt] 
\tikzset{level distance=60pt}=[draw, rectangle]
\Tree [.{Probability of Financial Crisis}  
     [.Fiscal  ]
     [.Banking  ]
     [.Currency ] 
     ]

\begin{scope}[xshift=-3in,every tree node/.style={},edge from parent path={}]
\Tree [.{Objective/Goal:} [.{Criteria:} ]]
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


But the problem is, where i have the labels they seem to be slightly lowered than the corresponding tree diagram.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just for the record, the tree as produced using the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package; notice the economy in code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
  draw,
  minimum height=2cm,
  anchor=north,
  align=center,
  child anchor=north
},
[{Supplier\\Selection}, align=center, name=SS
  [{Production\\Development\\Capability}, name=PDC
    [Max Size, name=MS]
    [{Casting\\Complexity}]
    [{Min. Sec.\\Thickness}]
    [{Software\\ Aid}]
    [{Pattern\\Making}]
  ]
  [{Manufacturing\\Capability}]
  [{Quality\\Capability}]
  [{Cost and \\Time}
   [{Total\\Costing\\Cost}]
   [{Sample\\Delivery\\Time}]
  ]
]
\node[anchor=west,align=left] 
  at ([xshift=-2cm]MS.west) {Level 3\\Criteria};
\node[anchor=west,align=left] 
  at ([xshift=-2cm]MS.west|-PDC) {Level 2\\ Group Criteria};
\node[anchor=west,align=left] 
  at ([xshift=-2cm]MS.west|-SS) {Level 1\\Overall Objective};
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is one possible solution

[image]

Note: If arrow lines are preferred, add a style to the `\tikzset{...}` as shown below.

```
edge from parent/.style={draw=black!70,-latex}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [auto,every node/.style={rectangle,draw, text centered, text width=2.2cm,minimum height=1.5cm },node distance=6cm]
\tikzset{%
level 1/.style={sibling distance = 5cm, level distance=2cm,edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}},
level 2/.style={sibling distance = 2.5cm,level distance=3cm}
}
  \node (0){Supplier \\ Selection}
    child {node (1) {Production \\ Development \\Capability}
              child {node (2) {Max sixe}}
              child {node {Casting\\Complexity}}
              child {node {Min. Sec.\\Thickness}}
              child {node {Software\\Aid}}
              child {node {Pattern\\Making}}}
    child {node {Manufacturing\\Capability}}
    child {node {Quality\\Capabiltity}}
    child {node {Cost and\\Time}
              child {node {Total\\ Casting\\ Cost}}
              child {node {Sample\\Delivery\\Time}}};
\node at (0) [xshift=-11cm,left,draw=none]{Level 1};
\node at (1) [xshift=-6cm, left,draw=none]{Level 2};
\node at (2) [xshift=-1cm, left,draw=none]{Level 3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```