# How can I draw this schemas in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw these schemas in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) To give you an idea where to start from: [How can I draw simple trees in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5447/134144), [How can I reproduce this simple tree diagram?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/326449/134144)  and [How can I produce this tree diagram in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161231/134144)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use forest for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={draw,edge={-latex},parent anchor=south,align=left}
[Ontological models and languages\\ 
for mathematical knowledge management\\ 
on the Semantic Web 
 [Terminological Ressources\\ and Symbolic Notation\\ for Mathematical domain
  [Terminological Ressources
   [Vocabularies
    [The Online Encyclopedia\\ of Integer Sequences]
   ]
   [pft112
    [pft1121]
    [pft1122]
   ]  
  ]
  [pft12
   [pft121
    [pft1211]
   ]
   [pft122
    [pft1221]
   ]  
   [pft123
    [pft1231]
   ]  
  ]
 ]
 [pft2
  [pft21
   [pft211]
   [pft212]  
  ]
  [pft22]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version with a title and using [Zarko's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492100/how-can-i-draw-this-schemas-in-latex/492104?noredirect=1#comment1242572_492104) for the `tier`s.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={draw,edge={-latex},parent anchor=south,align=left,
tier/.option=level% <-from Zarko's comment
}
[Ontological models and languages\\ 
for mathematical knowledge management\\ 
on the Semantic Web,alias=root 
 [Terminological Ressources\\ and Symbolic Notation\\ for Mathematical domain
  [Terminological Ressources
   [Vocabularies
    [The Online Encyclopedia\\ of Integer Sequences]
   ]
   [pft112
    [pft1121]
    [pft1122]
   ]  
  ]
  [pft12
   [pft121
    [pft1211]
   ]
   [pft122
    [pft1221]
   ]  
   [pft123
    [pft1231]
   ]  
  ]
 ]
 [pft2
  [pft21
   [pft211]
   [pft212]  
  ]
  [pft22]
 ]
]
\node[above=0.5em of current bounding box,font=\large\bfseries]{My title};
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Halima You're welcome! I also added something that addresses the question of too long text. You basically have to say `align=<something>`, where `<something>` can be left, center or something analogous. The way this site works is that if you have additional questions, you can simply ask a new one, which is free of charge after all. The answer fields are only for answers to the original question. If an answer solves your problem, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark left of it.

Comment: I would add  `tier/.option=level` into `for tree= {...}`.

Comment: thanks again, can I add a title to this schema?

Comment: @Halima What do you mean by title?

Answer (score 3):

You may start at this

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\node[draw] (1) {Blah blah level 1};
\node[draw,below left=1cm and 2cm of 1.south] (2-1) {Level 2 first thing};
\node[draw,below right=1cm and 2cm of 1.south] (2-2) {Level 2 second thing};
\draw[->] (1) -- (2-1);
\draw[->] (1) -- (2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Sorry, but we do not want to draw everything from scratch. You have to do it yourself based on our answers.